# Error in Calculating the sum of a filtered column value using Django Queries

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, aggregation

I have 2 models

```
class Horses(models.Model):
race = models.IntegerField(null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
owners = models.ManyToManyField(Owners)

class BetOrders(models.Model):
customers =models.ForeignKey(Customers, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
horses = models.ForeignKey(Horses, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
amountBet = models.FloatField(null = True)
horseprice = models.IntegerField(null=True)
timeOfBet = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of `amountBet` based on similar horse name.
i have tried this query set but in vain

```
BetOrders.objects.filter(horses__name='white river').annotate(total_sales=Sum('amountBet'))
```

May I Know whats wrong with this Query? and what is the correct way to get the Sum of the filtered value.
**Note: horse name is a FK.**
Here is a representation of my Table

```
+-------+------------------+
| Horse Name  | Amount Bet |
+-------------+------------+
| jals jiger  |    50      |
| white river |    80      |
| white river |    70      |
| jals jiger  |    10      |
| jals jiger  |    98      |
| chivas      |    10      |
+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a Group By query, you need to trigger the 'Group By' by using .values() with .annotate().  Try the below:

```
BetOrders.objects.values('horses__name').annotate(total_sales=Sum('amountBet')).filter(horses__name='white river')
```